# How to provide a minimum width for rich:orderingList control

Tags: jsf, richfaces

We use [rich:orderingList](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_orderingList.html) with the following attributes listHeight="auto" listWidth="auto", this causes it to auto re-size and if there are smaller strings within the list, the list width is very small. We would prefer to have a minimum size for smaller strings and should change to auto for larger strings. How do we achieve this?

Comment: I didn't understand: if you use auto for the width - it takes which width? the smaller size strings or the longer sized strings?

Comment: @Odelya It takes longer width ,but he wants to fix the minimum width say 100 now doesn't matter how small string is it should be atleast of 100 , but if there is any string with length more than 100 it width should be increase accordingly in `auto` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width each column separately and with EL expression set width either fixed size or auto.

So if for example your Item value is of type `String`

```
<rich:orderingList value="#{bean.simpleItems}" var="item" selection="#{bean.selection}" controlsType="button">
    <rich:column width="#{item.name.length > 100 ? 'auto' : '100px'}">
          <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Car Name" />
           </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
     </rich:column>
 </rich:orderingList>
```

Another option is through `columnClasses` property of rich:orderingList. You can define in the backing bean the CSS classes considering the maximum width of each String, and using it as ELExperssion: `columnClasses="#{myBean.columnWidth}"`

Comment: thanks for the excellent suggestion, we are using the first option

Comment: Hello Guys , I  am stuck to implement rich:orderingList http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819362/error-to-implement-richorderinglist-error-value-is-not-valid plz help me. where I am goint to wrong.